# How to use Caja (file manager) to organize files and folders online?

Tags: linux-mint, file-manager

The default file manager of `Linux Mint 15 (Mate)` is `Caja`. In the about screen of `Caja`, it says:

> Caja lets you organize files and folders, both on your computer and
>   **online**.

My question is, how could `Caja` be used to organize files and folders online? Does it mean it can be used as an FTP client?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, IIRC. I believe it can be used for FTP, though I'm not 100% sure.

What I suspect it's talking about, though, is Samba shares. (It may also be able to do `sshfs` but I'm not sure.)

All the magic happens through GVFS (or whatever the MATE guys called the GNOME 2 equivalent, GVS, when they forked it).

Answer (score -1):

Yes it supports both FTP and VSFTP. [See here](http://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/which-is-faster-ssh-or-ftp/)

Comment: vsftp is the name of a particular program that provides FTP and SFTP (among other similar protocols) -- you probably mean the latter. :-)

Comment: Exactly ;) @ChrisDown